# xcache -Fatal error: Call to undefined function xcache_isset()?

Tags: php, function, undefined, xcache

I have successfully installed xcache.  And add xcache config in php.ini. And also restart apache server.

My system is mac os x 10.7.3.

php -v (or show phpinfo):

```
PHP 5.3.8 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Nov 15 2011 15:33:15) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2011 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2011 Zend Technologies
    with Zend Debugger v5.2, Copyright (c) 1999-2009, by Zend Technologies
    with XCache v2.0.0, Copyright (c) 2005-2012, by mOo
```

xcache config:

```
[xcache-common]
zend_extension = "/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xcache.so"

[xcache.admin]
xcache.admin.auth = On
xcache.admin.user = "mOo"
; xcache.admin.pass = md5($your_password)
xcache.admin.pass = ""

[xcache]
xcache.shm_scheme =        "mmap"
xcache.size  =               60M
xcache.count =                 1
xcache.slots =                8K
xcache.ttl   =                 0
xcache.gc_interval =           0
xcache.var_size  =            4M
xcache.var_count =             1
xcache.var_slots =            8K
xcache.var_ttl   =             0
xcache.var_maxttl   =          0
xcache.var_gc_interval =     300
xcache.readonly_protection = Off
xcache.mmap_path =    "/tmp/xcache"
xcache.coredump_directory =   ""
xcache.cacher =               On
xcache.stat   =               On
xcache.optimizer =           Off
xcache.test =                Off
xcache.experimental =        Off

[xcache.coverager]
xcache.coverager =          Off
xcache.coveragedump_directory = ""
```

**All looks like OK.  But when I run the following code, get a error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function xcache_isset().**

PHP CODE:

```
<?php
if(!xcache_isset("test")) {
    xcache_set("test", strftime('%Y-%m-%d %A %H:%M:%S', time()), 30);
}
echo xcache_get("test");
```

What is the problem caused by?

Answer (score 0):

You could put in a if(function_exists()..
You could also put in an @ sign in front of it.

Try removing that line of code and see if the other xcache functions are available. If there not also, then I'd be questioning if the extension is properly loaded..  if they are working okay, then when was the xcache_isset function introduced (xcache version), is it worth upgrading the xcache version ?